# on ubutu14.04, when i tried ti install jekyll with command 'gem install jekyll, iget an error

Tags: jekyll

The error is -

> Loading command: install (LoadError)  cannot load such file -- zlib
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)     undefined method
>   `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Please tell the possible reason for this error and help in resoving it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is discussed here. It is also solved. Their findings might help you:

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/55

From the link:

> Great! It's all working! I followed this steps:
>   First i removed all previously installed rubies on my OS.
>   And next this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.2
rvm use 2.1.2 --default
gem install jekyll
```